# "Upgrade must be run with administrator rights" message is displayed while running upgrade command for JTS

Tags: command-line, administrator, rational-team-concert

I am upgrading Collaborative lifecycle management version to 6.0.5 current version is 5.0.2. As specified in IBM Interactive upgrade guide one of the step is to run upgrade script on your databases and below are the command

```
cd D:\IBM\JazzTeamServer6.0.5\server    
upgrade\jts\jts_upgrade.bat -oldJTSHome "D:\IBM\JazzTeamServer5.x\server\conf" -updateTomcatFiles no -updateAppServerFiles no
```

After  running this command I am getting message as "Upgrade must be run with administrator rights"
I am logged in as administrative user on the system, assigned all the full access control permission of folder where CLM server is installed to user still everytime same problem persist.
I was going through links to troubleshoot the problem but nothing seems to be working out for me. Some of the links I have referred are
https://www.techsupportall.com/how-to-enable-administrator-account-on-welcome-screen/
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/elevated-privileges-windows
Can anyone please suggest I am missing anything here?

Comment: Is it possible the "administrator rights" mentioned by jts_upgrade.bat is actually an application account (ie do the upgrade with an account which is already administrator of the jts CLM instance)?

Comment: If not I will monitor https://jazz.net/forum/questions/252467/upgrade-must-be-run-with-administrator-rights

Comment: One of the prerequisites before running the upgrade command is user should have admin access rights of the system and should have full control over directory where CLM is installed. To run upgrade command we require system admin rights. Also it is not specified in command to provide admin credentials for application.

Comment: I am using windows server 2016 Datacenter. Could there be any additional setting in this OS

Comment: Try and check if you have read/write access to the "directory where CLM is installed".

Comment: Full Access controls are given to user including read and write access.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by User Account Control, a feature which makes so that, even if you have administrative rights, you don't actually have them unless you explicitly request them. There are two distinct policies governing UAC behaviour (both found in Computer settings\Windows settings\Security settings\Local policies\Security options), one for the built-in Administrator account, and another one for all other administrative users:

User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account (disabled by default)
User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode (enabled by default)
What this means is: by default, the built-in Administrator account is not affected by UAC, while all other administrative users are; thus, it's possible for an administrative user (different from the built-it Administrator) to not actually have administrative rights, even if it's a member of the Administrators group.

More info -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd835564(v=ws.10)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. I set value of "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode (enabled by default)" to disabled, restarted the system and run the command. Same problem persisted